# CSS Hover not showing

Tags: html, css, filter, hover

Okay, so I have an image for a background that has 1px of a blur filter in the CSS.

That works.

*Then*, I added a CSS :hover selector to a *new* CSS rule that changes the blur filter to 0.

When I hover over it on the browser, however, it doesn't change the blur at all! (I went into Google Chrome Inspect Element and used the handy feature of forcing the :hover selector, and then it worked. So I know it's not the CSS that's buggy.)

How can I get this to work? It's a blur filter on a div in a header. Any ideas?

```
    <header>
        <div id="bgimage"></div>
        <nav>
            <a href="home.html" title="Click to go to the homepage.">Home</a>
            <span class="divider">-</span>
            <a href="cakes.html" title="Click to see types of cakes.">Types of Cake</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>Cakes</h1>
    </header>

body header {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:4;
    position:relative;
    background-color:linear-gradient(CornFlowerBlue,RoyalBlue);
}
body header div#bgimage {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:url(hydrangea-cakes-2.jpg);
    filter:blur(1px);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The important parts of the HTML are the header and the div id="bgimage"

Comment: Another element might be capturing the hover event.  We can't tell, though, without seeing some of the code.  Can you post an example of the issue or at least provide the markup and styles?

Comment: let me edit the post real quick

Answer (score 1):

You haven't already added the `:hover` pseudo-class.

```css
#bgimage:hover {
  /* the styles you want to display on hover */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the `:hover` part of the CSS but it works for me if I just add this to the CSS:

```
#bgimage:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```